# IntelliJ disable automatic line splitting

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Recently I updated to the newest version of IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4 Ultimate.
Since this update it automatically splits lines for me which is very annoying because I'd like to do that by myself manually.

Example:
I might be typing something like this:

```
throw new IllegalArgumentException("You can only provide one vararg/optional parameter to the end of this method!");
```

And while typing intellij automatically continues on a new line:

```
throw new IllegalArgumentException("You can only provide one vararg/optional parameter to the end of this" +
                    " method!");
```

Now this might seem fine, but is really annoying when intelli decides to do it when you are writing a decimal double for example as it creates errors like this:
[image]

How can I disable this feature/modify this behaviour?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can edit the Code Style Settings at:

```
File > Settings > Editor > Code Style > Java > Wrapping and Braces
```

There are different options, for your problem set *Right margin column* to 300 or something like this or just uncheck *Ensure right margin it not exceeded*. You can also experiment with them.

Press `Ctrl + Alt + L` to format afterwards. Unfortunately once IntelliJ has wrapped the lines I am not sure if it unwraps them on its own, maybe you have to fix this.

Please consider when changing line length etc. that sometimes line length is needed due to Code Conventions, Checkstyle and those... :)

Update Screenshot:
[image: Margin]

Comment: This was the right answer for me (others didn't work). Thank you!

Answer (score 34):

Go to Intellij Settings and follow the instructions on these two pictures:

[image: Click Here]

Comment: Removing `Wrap on typing` did the trick for me. Thank god, what an annoying "feature".

Answer (score 10):

For a specific file use the Soft wraps option under the View/Active Editor menu item.

[image: Enable/Disable Soft Wraps on a file]

Answer (score 1):

for phpstorm 2016.2.1

go to `editor->code style->right margin(columns)`
change default `200` to `400+`
That's it!